# Determine build success/fail in Flash Builder

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder, build-automation, growlnotify

I'm trying to add a post-build task to my Flex project in Flash Builder 4.6.  Specifically, I want to send a Growl notification via `growlnotify`.  I can do this easily by going to `<project> → Properties → Builders` and adding it there.

However, the task will run regardless of whether the build succeeded or failed.  I would like the Growl notification to have a different message depending on build success/failure (or possibly have a different 'success task' and 'failure task').

Is it possible to determine the build status so I can do this?